# What does *((int *) arg) do?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, type-conversion

I'm not familiar with the terminology to describe `*((int *) arg)` so I've been unable to successfully Google query the topic in order to find out more about it; I was unsuccessful in finding anything here on SO either.

Here is a snippit of code from [The Linux Programming Interface](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/book/threads/thread_incr.c.html):

```
static void *threadFunc(void *arg)
{
   int loops = *((int *) arg)
   ...
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   pthread_t t1;
   int loops, s;

   loops = (argc > 1) ? getInt(argv[1], GN_GT_0, "num-loops") : 10000000;
   s = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, threadFunc, &loops);
   ...
}
```

What is `int loops = *((int *) arg)` doing and what is this phenomena called? Thanks.

Comment: You are casting a `void*` to an `int*` and then dereferencing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's combining pointer dereferencing `*some_pointer` with casting `(some_type)some_value_with_some_other_type`. What this does is basically "Hey C compiler, I know you think this is a `void*` but I think it should be an `int*`, can you please treat it as such? Oh, and while you're at it, give me the `int` the pointer is pointing to".

Comment: The conversation-like quote was a good approach; thank you. Totally makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

`arg` is a pointer that stores the address of a variable of type `int`

```
s = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, threadFunc, &loops);
                                          ^^^^^^
```

However in the function `threadFunc`  it is declared as having type `void *` instead of `int *`

```
static void *threadFunc(void *arg)
                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

Thus in this expression

```
int loops = *((int *) arg)
```

the pointer at first interpretated again as a pointer of type `int *`

```
(int *) arg
```

and then it is dereferenced that to get the object it points to

```
*((int *) arg)
```

Comment: So basically we pass the address of `loops` through `threadFunc()`. At the start of `threadFunc()`, `arg` is simply a void pointer that points to the address of `loops`. We then cast `arg` from a `void *` to `int *`, and then deference `arg` to get the int value that is `loops`? Sound about right?

Answer (score 1):

It reads integer of type 'int' from the memory address in pointer variable 'arg'. The '(int *)' is a type cast so that the compiler reinterprets the bits as pointer-to-int instead of pointer-to-void.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the `arg` I assume the pointer will hold a pointer to a function, this technique is used a lot in Linux and what you should probably look for is `callbacks` which are functions that are called with specific conditions and programmers often declare a variable that holds a generic prototype for a callback (in your case one that takes a pointer to an integer) and assign a callback to that pointer depending on the event and then call it when needed.